# How can I move a folder in textmate?

Tags: textmate

Textmate is really cute and nice with many things, except when it comes to moving a directory around. Any suggestions?

Comment: Holy poop. I just went to record a screenflow of it working, and yep it's not working for me. Hrmmm. I can see how this is now quite annoying. But I always have Terminal open so no worries I guess. I've deleted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately TextMate does not move folders. I do it by Finder or Terminal.